# Outlook: How to avoid that not-yet edited appointments appear in the calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

At work, I'm using Outlook 360 Enterprise.

In the last time, I observe the following strange behaviour:

I create a new appointment. After clicking the "new appointment" button, a window opens where I can enter the time and the title of the appointment.

So far so good.

However, at the same time a second window pops up, telling me that I have an unnamed appointment in a few minutes.

The reason:

Outlook does not create the appointment in the calendar when I click the "Save" button after entering the title and the time of the appointment.

Instead, Outlook already creates the appointment in the calendar when clicking the "new appointment" button using default data (an empty title and the current time as starting time).

By clicking the "Save" button, the appointment is not created in the calendar but the already existing appointment is modified.

By closing the window (cancelling the appointment creation), the existing dummy appointment remains in the calendar.

Is it possible to change this behaviour back to "normal" (so the appointment is created in the calendar when I click the "Save" button)?

Comment: You should ask the support people at your work. They may have set something up in Exchange for this. So long as I have an appointment in my own Outlook, I can save it properly without issue.

Comment: Agree with John, I could also save my appointment normally in Outlook 365 client. As a supplement， some add-ins may also cause it, it's recommended to restart your Outlook in safe mode to test(windows + R>type "Outlook.exe /safe>enter")